# ReactJs, the SyntaxError with `static defaultProps`

Tags: reactjs

I use the React to write this demo. I use the Webpack to build this demo.When I start this demo, the error will show me.

> ERROR in ./src/app.js
>   Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (8:24)

```
 import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
class Button extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

    }
    static defaultProps = {
        color:'blue',
        text: 'Confirm',
    }
    render (){
        return (
            <button className={'btn btn-${color}'}>
                <em>{text}</em>
                <p>This is a button.</p>
            </button>
        );
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Button />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

I read this demo from a book. Due to the book is probably print the wrong code. So I ask this question now.

The error show `static defaultProps = {` is not  right. The book is also written with this form.  Do you know the right code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be some error in your `webpack` setup. Otherwise `defaultProps` is defined correctly as it should be.

One more thing to access the props you need to use `this.props.propName`

Check the below code -

```js
class Button extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

    }
    static defaultProps = {
        color:'blue',
        text: 'Confirm'
    }
    render (){
        return (
            <button className={'btn btn-${this.props.color}'}>
                <em>{this.props.text}</em>
                <p>This is a button.</p>
            </button>
        );
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Button />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 7):

The terminal executes `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-0` in the current directory.

Add `stage-0` to the current directory * .babelrc * file

`{
   "Presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-0"],
}}`