# Setting up git npm dependency for debugging

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, npm, webpack

First time trying to do this, so not really sure what I am doing or how to set it up.

I need to debug a library I am using in my application. Originally, I had it installed with `npm install @react-pdf/renderer`. That wouldn't work well for debugging and I came across this answer describing how to work on a dependency if you need to make modifications to it:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13302095/3123109

So now I'm doing `npm install https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/tarball/master` which puts a copy of the repo into my `node_modules`.

I was under the impression it would "just work" after doing this. Of course not that simple...

---

**What I have tried**

1. I have NPM running on my application. The first error that comes up is `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@react-pdf/renderer'` in my component where it is contained. Ok, so updated my `import` to the following to look at the `index.js` of the library: `import { Document } from '@react-pdf/renderer/src`.
2. Clears up that message. Now I get:

   ```
   ERROR in /mnt/c/Users/User/projects/current/client/node_modules/@react-pdf/renderer/src/elements/Page.js 11:22
   Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11:22)
   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
   |
   | class Page extends Base {
   >   static defaultProps = {
   |     size: 'A4',
   |     orientation: 'portrait',
   @ /mnt/c/Users/User/projects/current/client/node_modules/@react-pdf/renderer/src/elements/index.js 3:0-26 13:8-12
   @ /mnt/c/Users/User/projects/current/client/node_modules/@react-pdf/renderer/src/index.js
   ```

Looking into it, it sounds like it is a `babel-preset-stage-0` issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41412906/3123109

Ok, I add that to `.babelrc` in the `@react-pdf/renderer` since it is missing. Same issue.

3. I guess I need to add it to my `.babelrc` which also requires doing `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-0` (even though I don't use that in my app, but whatever). Get this error:

   ```
   ERROR in ../react/index.jsx
   Module build failed (from /mnt/c/Users/User/projects/current/client/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
   Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions.
   ```

Apparently had to do with mixing Babel 6 with Babel 7, the former being related to the `stage-0` and the latter being what I am using in my application.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49183337/3123109

Ok, apparently a dependency issue going on that I'm not sure how to resolve given I've never done this before. That being said, when I did the `npm install https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/tarball/master`, it did install the dependencies in `node_module` for `@react-pdf/renderer`.

---

**Questions**

1. Do I need to be installing the dependencies for `@react-pdf/renderer` even though it looks like they were installed with `npm install https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/tarball/master`?
2. If so, where? Do the dependencies need to be added to my app (via adding them to my `package.json`) or within the `node_modules/@react-pdf/renderer` directory via `npm install` in that directory?
3. Do I need to be running `npm run ... --watch` for `@react-pdf/renderer` in addition to running it for my app?
4. Or, do I just need to be taking the compiled JS files for `@react-pdf/renderer`, reading them into my app, then recompiling the JS if I need to make changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the developer of `@react-pdf/renderer` gave me a hand setting up. The way he suggested, as I'm sure there are several ways to do this, was using `yarn`:

1. Clone react-pdf repo in a separate folder
2. Run `yarn install` in react-pdf dir
3. Run `yarn link` in react-pdf dir. This will link the lib to your local version
4. Run `yarn watch` in react-pdf dir. This will watch for file changes and re-bundle every time
5. Run `yarn link "@react-pdf/renderer"` in your project to use local bundle

I'd image replacing "`yarn`" with "`npm`" would work, but haven't tested it out.

Ya learn something new everyday...

Comment: do we need to run `yarn watch` everytime we power on the system?